# Alternative to WWW::Mechanize::Firefox script to run on a server?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

I have a cloud server and would like to run this script on a cron job, unfortunately it requires `Firefox` to be installed with `MozRepl` and `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`. I don't think I can run the script without it installed on the server and I don't think I can get it installed as there is no desktop.

I'm no expert.

what can I do, other than run the scipt on my local but update the db on server?

Comment: Checking assumptions: do you need WWW::Mechanize::Firefox, or will a more lightweight library like WWW::Mechanize do the trick?

Comment: Installing Firefox does not need a "desktop" (whatever this means).

Comment: So you are saying everything should run smooth provided the mozrepl plugin is installed, activated and firefox is running?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` if your requirement is to merely webscrape there are multiple options available that do not require a browser installed.

A popular choice is [ScraPY](https://scrapy.org/) which comes with all the bells and whistles and is built with python

No browser required